# How to find the eof of a Visual Foxpro dbf file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-foxpro

So I'm opening a visual foxpro dbf file in python. I'm trying to make a statement:

```
    if eof(): 
       Do something
    else:
       Do something
```

As I recall Python 3 doesn't use Eof so is there any solution on how I know if I reached the end of the file ?

Here is where I open my dbf file and my for loop loops through the dbf file but I want it where I can see if it's eof first before it loop through.

```
    mhvupload_table = DBF('C:\Sonichr\\mhvupload.DBF', recfactory=None,load =True,ignore_missing_memofile=True)
    for mhvupload_rec in mhvupload_table:
```

Comment: When your "for ... in ..." loop finishes, you would be at EOF, no?

Comment: I don't use Python and don't know which library you are using, but one of Pyhton libs with DBF() has Eof. ie: table.Eof.

Comment: Yes I would be at eof in the end of my for loop and what dbf is it?

Comment: Is that a question or do you mean that you understood?

Comment: I understand the first portion not the second.

Comment: Which portion? I only said one the libs that has DBF() in Python has already an Eof. I don't know which lib you are using. Did you ever check the documentation of what you are using?

Comment: import dbf 
from dbfread import DBF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you don't understand. I don't know Python, but anyway I tried this and works exactly as I said:

```
from dbfread import DBF
table = DBF('C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9/Samples/Northwind/Customers.dbf')


def DoIfNotEof(object):
    print(object)

def DoIfEof():
    print("\nEnd Of File is reached. Going to sleep.")

for record in table:
    DoIfNotEof(record)
DoIfEof()
```

As I see, that dbfread doesn't read 100% correctly (stripping long field names) but is working anyway. Probably there is a setting or something. Try visiting [DaboDev](https://dabodev.com). Those guys are former VFP developers.